# Spring Security OAuth2 with custom TokenGranter in version 2.0.+

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config, spring-security-oauth2

In previous versions of OAuth2 it was possible to add a custom token granter by adding it to the xml configuration in the `<authorization-server>` element.

I wonder how I could extend the authorization server with Java Config using a AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter, without losing the default configuration, which contains the implicit, client credentials, refresh token and authorization code grant types.

First attempt was using creating the TokenGranter with @Component:

```
@Component("customTokenGranter")
public class CustomTokenGranter {
     //implementation
}
```

This leads to a dependency resolution exception because the tokenServices needed to construct the Granter cannot be autowired.

Second attempt was using the configure method

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception
{
    endpoints
        .tokenGranter(new CustomTokenGranter(endpoints.getTokenServices(),
                endpoints.getClientDetailsService(), endpoints.getOAuth2RequestFactory()));

}
```

Using this, the default grant types will not be registered.

I also tried a second configuration with a lower order, but without success.
What else could I do to add my custom grant type?

Answer (score 11):

You need to add the default ones too, e.g. using a `CompositeTokenGranter`:

```
        List<TokenGranter> tokenGranters = getTokenGranters(); // implementation up to you
        tokenGranter = new CompositeTokenGranter(tokenGranters);
        endpoints.tokenGranter(tokenGranter);
```

Comment: I solved it by developing a decorator for the original CompositeTokenGranter which can be initialized with the result of endpoints.getTokenGranter(). The decorator has also an add method to add additional granters. Then in the grant method I try the custom granters first and then delegate to the original CompositeTokenGranter.

Comment: FYI: There seems to be a mistake in the documentation. The TokenGranter has to be configured with the AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer  - the documentation says it should be the AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.

Comment: did you not get into issues when calling `endpoints.getTokenGranter()`? because `clientDetailsService` (within `endpoints` is not properly initialized at this stage.
and you also can't use `endpoints.clientDetailsService(clientDetailsService)` to set it, as `yooture.web.config.SecurityOauth2Configuration.AuthorizationServerConfiguration.configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer)` will still be called and overwrite some references again.

Comment: @domi Yes I am getting the issue like this. Even without a custom granter the authentication does not work when using composite granter in this way. Has anyone been able to crack this?

Comment: I believe that issue doesn't exist in master (which will be 2.0.8). You can try it and see (there's a sample in github).

Comment: Where can I find the example? I could not find anything at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2 ?

Comment: Did you look in the integration tests (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation)?

Comment: A custom `OAuth2RequestFactory` is failing to manage `csrf` token updating between the `/oauth/authorize` and `/oauth/token` endpoints.  Are you willing to comment?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061697/invalid-xsrf-token-at-oauth-token

Answer (score 11):

Here is another way.  [Copied from here.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/custom-grant/src/main/java/demo/Application.java)

In this example, a new custom `TokenGranter`, named `CustomTokenGranter`, is added to a `CompositeTokenGranter` with the default `TokenGranters`.  I like this example because it uses the `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`'s public method `getTokenGranter()` to retrieve the default `TokenGranter`'s.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        endpoints.tokenGranter(tokenGranter(endpoints));
    }

    private TokenGranter tokenGranter(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        List<TokenGranter> granters = new ArrayList<TokenGranter>(Arrays.asList(endpoints.getTokenGranter()));
        granters.add(new CustomTokenGranter(endpoints.getTokenServices(), endpoints.getClientDetailsService(), endpoints.getOAuth2RequestFactory(), "custom"));
        return new CompositeTokenGranter(granters);
    }
```

Comment: Hi the AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoint TokenGranters is null on start up. Could you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @NinjaDude add a new list.

Comment: I mean endpoints.getTokenGranter() == null when i start up my spring boot application. i put a debug point and saw it. so essentially, there is only CustomTokenGranter present. The rest of the default Token Granters are missing (eg refreshtoken, authorization code granter etc).

Comment: @NinjaDude

List<TokenGranter> granters = endpoints.getTokenGranter() == null
? New ArrayList<>()
: new ArrayList<TokenGranter>(Arrays.asList(endpoints.getTokenGranter()));

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find a way to do it because of the dependency on ClientDetailService making it difficult to get the default granters from the getTokenGranter method. I copied over the code from AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer#tokenGranter() and passed in my clientDetailService and other beans directly to the constructors. Note that I add to create a DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory to pass to the granters and to the endpoints:

```
public TokenGranter tokenGranter() {

            ClientDetailsService clientDetails = clientDetailsService;
            AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices = tokenServices();
            AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices = authorizationCodeServices();
            OAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = requestFactory();

            List<TokenGranter> tokenGranters = new ArrayList<TokenGranter>();

            tokenGranters.add(new AuthorizationCodeTokenGranter(tokenServices, authorizationCodeServices,
                    clientDetails, requestFactory));
            tokenGranters.add(new RefreshTokenGranter(tokenServices, clientDetails, requestFactory));
            tokenGranters.add(new ImplicitTokenGranter(tokenServices, clientDetails, requestFactory));
            tokenGranters.add(new ClientCredentialsTokenGranter(tokenServices, clientDetails, requestFactory));
            tokenGranters.add(new ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter(authenticationManager, tokenServices,
                        clientDetails, requestFactory));
            tokenGranters.add(new CustomTokenGranter(authenticationManager, tokenServices(), clientDetailsService,
                    requestFactory));

            return new CompositeTokenGranter(tokenGranters);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints
                .tokenServices(tokenServices())
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer())
                .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .requestFactory(requestFactory())
                .tokenGranter(tokenGranter());
    }
```

That being said, I ended up removing that code and simply added another AuthenticationProvider instead because my new grant type was using a subclass of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken anyway, which is the Authentication type used by the password grant by default.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, we have :

> Grant Types
>
> The grant types supported by the AuthorizationEndpoint can be
>   configured via the AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer. By default
>   all grant types are supported except password (see below for details
>   of how to switch it on). The following properties affect grant types:
>
> authenticationManager: password grants are switched on by injecting an
>   AuthenticationManager. 
>   ......

See [documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html).
So you can inject the AuthenticationManager like this :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationServerConfigurer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
........
```